# Expected transition time for a infinite state space DTMC

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, birth-death-process

I have the following discrete-time Markov chain defined on the state space $S:=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$:
$$p(i,j) = \begin{cases}
1, \quad &\text{if $i=0$ and $j=1$}\\
\frac{1}{2}, \quad &\text{if $j=i-1$ and $i=1,2,\ldots$}\\
\frac{i-1}{2(i+1)}, \quad &\text{if $j=i$ and $i=1,2,\ldots$}\\
\frac{1}{i+1}, \quad &\text{if $j=i+1$ and $i=1,2,\ldots$}\\
0, \quad &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

In other words, 
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1/2 & 0 &1/2\\
 & 1/2& 1/(2*3)&1/3\\
&&1/2&2/(2*4)&1/4\\
&&&1/2&3/(2*5)&1/5\\
&&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

This question uses the same DTMC used in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496801/finding-the-stationary-distribution-for-this-discrete-time-markov-chain-dtmc). Unfortunately I'm stuck with another piece of this problem.

I am asked to find the expected number of steps it will take to reach state 0 given that I start in state 1. I tried using a first-step analysis to solve this problem, but it creates an infinite system of equations that I don't know how to solve. Specifically, let $\tau_0$ be the random variable representing the number of steps needed to state 0. Let $\mathbb{E}_i[\cdot]= \mathbb{E}[\ \cdot \ | \ X_0 = i]$ and let $\mathbb{P}_i(\cdot) = \mathbb{P}(\ \cdot \ | \ X_0 = i)$.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_1[\tau_0] &= \mathbb{P}_1(X_1 = 0)\mathbb{E}_0[\tau_0] + \mathbb{P}_1(X_1 = 2)\mathbb{E}_2[\tau_0]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (1) + \frac{1}{2} (\mathbb{E}_2[\tau_0]+1)
\end{align*}

Then If we try to calculate $\mathbb{E}_2[\tau_0]$, we get a function of $\mathbb{E}_3[\tau_0]$, and this will produce an infinite system of equations that I don't know what to do with.

EDIT: In the linked question above, the stationary distribution is found.

Comment: I disagree with your equation, if I understand your notation correctly it should be $$ E_1 = (1/2)(1) + (1/2)(1+E_2)$$

Comment: Anyway you can either solve the infinite number of linear equations or you can use mean-recurrence results that relate stationary distributions to mean recurrence times.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's a typo on my part. I have edited the post.

Comment: Is there any chance you could point me to a source that talks about mean-recurrence results? I can't say that I'm familiar with the concept.

Comment: Here is a link I found by googling "mean recurrence time is one over": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724529/mean-recurrence-time-and-stationary-distribution-of-a-markov-chain

Comment: Okay, thank you for the link: Here's my answer then. Since $\pi_0= \frac{1}{e^2}$, we have that $\mathbb{E}_0[\tau_0] = \frac{1}{1/e^2}=e^2$. Since we necessarily move from state 0 to state 1 in this Markov chain, $\mathbb{E}_1[\tau_0] = e^2-1$. I hope this looks right.

Comment: Yes, your answer $E_1 = \frac{1}{\pi_0}-1$ looks good. I assume your value for $\pi_0$ is correct as I have not verified that.  You can post your answer and evaluate it as "best answer," which is a standard practice when you solve it yourself based on hints in the comments.